# How to fix spelling error in a field or column value using Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns

There is a column whose values of form `CodeXX` has been misspelled as `Code-XX` in some of the records/rows. I want to merge all `Code-XX` to `CodeXX` while doing aggregation operation in Tableau.
How can I merge the misspelled data value with the correctly spelled one within a column?

Answer (score 0):

A calculate field should work for you, like so:

```
IF [column_name] = 'Code-XX'
THEN 'CodeXX'
ELSE [column_name]
END
```

Comment: In my ques, `XX` represents any two digit number. Say for example, `Code-10` or `Code-99` which should be mapped against `Code10` and `Code99` respectively. Hard coding won't work.

Comment: @SauravSahu you should have mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

```
Right Click on the Field > Create > Calculated Field > Give name to new field (say Code2)
```

Add this expression:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([code]  , '-' ,'')
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

The following calculation will work in your scenario.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE([Column],'\-','')
```

Use '\' to escape hyphen in your column.

[Original column and cleaned column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAozx.png)

Hope that helps!